# What's the net income of a W1/W2 german professor?

Tags: job-search, germany, salary

I've seen a job announcement where the salary was said to be comparable to the assistant/associate professor level W1/W2 in the German system, and I was wondering how much it would exactly make in terms of net income (i.e. after ALL taxes). 
I found this [link](http://www.eui.eu/ProgrammesAndFellowships/AcademicCareersObservatory/AcademicCareersbyCountry/Germany.aspx) that states that for Western provinces, it was in 2007 between 3400 and 3900 euros gross per month. This [other link](http://www.myscience.de/en/jobs_and_careers/salary) states that in Hessen (which is where the position is based), the gross monthly salary is 
5386 for W2 and 3901 for W1. Then, according to [this calculator](http://www.connectingindians.com/index.php?name=extraModule&file=GermanTaxCalculator), a 3900 gross salary means 2167 euros net, after all taxes. So my questions are:

1. Do these numbers make sense?
2. Are there intermediary ranks between W1 and W2?
3. How negotiable is the starting rank in general?
4. Are there bonuses to take into account when you're single with no child?
5. Is the tax system identical for german and non-german?

Comment: Two comments: 1) Isn't the relevance of this question VERY dependent on the time? I mean, one can only speculate whether or not the information here will reflect the reality in a years time. 2) I guess how much money one would make is also dependent on how much stuff is worth? In other words even if the salary is higher/lower than some other country of reference, the cost of living might also be higher/lower. So it's perhaps subjective to judge the numbers purely.

Comment: @posdef: 1) Yes, of course, it depends on the time, and the number probably won't make sense in 20 years. But having some numbers still give a relative idea. However, university positions tend to have a relative stability in terms of increase/decrease, and it's not likely to jump from 2000 to 5000 the following year, and then go back to 1000.

Comment: @posdef 2) Yes, but I can always look up on the Internet to have a rough idea of much would a flat cost, and based on my experience, that's a good indicator of the cost of living. So, if I see a nice flat for 800 euros per month, I can get a good idea how much I will spend on other parts, which is why it would be good to have an idea on how much the salary exactly is (especially when it comes to taxes).

Comment: Good points, hope it works out for the best :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The rules for a German professor are quite different than for a typical German employee. The first thing to note is that you will be a *Beamter*, which is a very special class of government employees. In particular, you are automatically exempted from the public healthcare system, as well as having to make direct payments into the social security system out of your paycheck. Instead, the pension payments are covered by your employer (the government of the *Land* in which you work), while the *Beihilfe* system helps to defray part of your insurance costs (the rest of which you pay for through a private insurance contract). In other words: you get billed for your health care; your private insurance reimburses you for 50 percent of your costs, and 30 percent of the costs for other family members. You submit the remainder of the bill to the university, which reimburses the remaining 50 percent (70 percent).

The net result of this is that you get a much higher percentage of your income as take-home pay relative to a traditional government employee. Your tax status depends on your marital status, so as a W1, you can expect to take home somewhere between 2800 and 3200 euros per month, as reported by the [Öffentlicher Dienst](http://oeffentlicher-dienst.info/beamte/) website. There are some differences due to cost of living in different states. However, expect to pay about 200 € per month for health care, or more if you have a family.

However, I should also note that just this week came down a new [ruling](http://blogs.nature.com/news/2012/02/young-german-profs-underpaid-court-says.html) from the German Federal Constitutional Court stating that the salaries for professors hired since 2005 are too low, and need to be adjusted. This has the potential to adjust salaries upwards somewhat—although it is not yet clear by how much. (The state of Hesse, against whom the ruling was made, has until January to adjust its salaries upwards.)

To answer your other questions:

- There are no ranks between W1 and W2.
- The base salary is nonnegotiable, as it's set by the state government for which you will work; however, you can negotiate some terms of your "package" (support for students and other workers), and you may be able to get some "performance bonuses" negotiated into the contract.
- Teaching duties are set by federal law, and are similarly nonnegotiable (although you can negotiate the ability, for instance, to teach in English rather than German)
- Bonuses are not available for single people with no children; instead, according to German law, they're actually taxed at a *higher* rate.
- There is no difference in salary based on nationality.

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, just one question though: what does cover the public part of the healthcare compared to the private one?

Comment: The _Beihilfe_ system is paid for by the government, so you submit your medical bills to the university for reimbursement. Edited to add this to the answer.

Comment: It's not exactly true that singles are taxed at a higher rate in Germany. The tax rate that couples pay is exactly that for half of their combined income, so the higher earning partner will in fact *appear to* have a lower rate. If both earn equal, they pay the same tax rate as a single.

Comment: Is it not a bit low for a university professor? I mean they generally work more than most of other civil servants. They also have a quite wide range of duties (teaching, supervising, publishing, etc). And of course they have to dedicate more years of hard work (in comparison to other public servants) to reach that level.

Comment: @Pouya this is about W1 and W2 professors. Especially W1 are often early career temporary positions where the person qualifies him or herself for a full professorship (W3). The W2 can be a similar temporary/qualifying position as W1 or a (semi) permanent (teaching) position below the level of full professor.

Comment: @MaartenBuis and aeismail: I'm a bit confused here; if W1 is temporary, how can it be a Beamter position (as per the 1st paragraph of this answer)? I thought Beamter means permanent.

Comment: The Beamter is a class of positions, one of which includes the W1, even though it is limited in duration. But I had the same tax withholding and had to follow the same policies as W2s and W3s even though I was a W1.

Comment: @amoeba W1 typically get the *Beamter auf Zeit* status, W3 typically get (eventually) the *Beamter auf Lebenszeit* status. W2 is such a mixed bag that that is hard to predict. You just have to look carefully at the exact conditions for that position, which is always a good idea anyway. So a Beamter status does not necessarily imply a permanent position in Germany.